# Cacti and MySQL Queries

Tags: linux, centos, mysql, cacti

I am new to Cacti and am interested in using it to perform some queries against a MySQL database. I have a software which logs an error counter into a MySQL table, and I'd like to be able to graph this with Cacti. How would I go about this? I've looked around but the only MySQL stuff I can find is getting information about the database itself, not actually performing queries. If it's not possible, can I write a PHP script which returns the value and Cacti graph that?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Found something which explained everything over here: http://www.cacti.net/downloads/docs/html/how_to.html